# Why would the keyword 'this' be recognized in one function but not another in the same Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined
```

in my Backbone view. It is saying it the `this` in my `updateModel` function is undefined.

But I don't understand why because I use `this` all throughout the rest of the view with no issues. They are all recognized.

Here is the code block that has the issue.  As you can see, I successfully use `this` elsewhere.

Why doesn't it work in my `updateModel` function?

```
events() {
    'click #moreData': 'renderMain',
},

render: function() {
    // bunch of code related to styling and changing css

    return this;
},

renderMain(e) {
    setTimeout(_.bind(this.loadData, this), 1);
},

loadData: function () {
    this.renderComponent(microPlane, {
        model: this.model, 
        updateModel: this.updateModel }, 
        '.modelLayout');
},

updateModel: function () {
    this.trigger('change', this.model);
}
```

I just can't figure it out :/

Comment: Because you bound loadData but not updateModel?

Comment: the `renderMain` function binds this scope to the loadData function

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh I see, so I could do the same to `updateModel` like `_.bind(this.updateModel, this)`  thanks I feel so dumb for not seeing this in my plain site

Comment: Canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/3001761